# Sull'uso figurato del verbo "sbraitare"

Tags: word-usage, verbs

Nel romanzo *Non so niente di te* di Paola Mastrocola, pubblicato da Einaudi, ho letto (il corsivo è mio):

> Ognuno ha il suo modo di non dormire, la notte, il suo stile, le sue tecniche di insonnia. C'è chi [...]. E c'è chi si ribella, non ammette, non concepisce che possa capitare a lui, è ostile, sbuffa, *sbraita*, finge di dormire, strizza gli occhi perché il sonno arrivi, si sforza di non pensarci e ci pensa sempre di piú, finendo per restare a letto teso come una corda di violino.

Siccome non conoscevo il significato del verbo "sbraitare", l'ho cercato nel [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/sbraitare/), dove ho trovato questa accezione del termine:

> protestare manifestando a voce alta il proprio risentimento: *s. contro il governo, contro le tasse; tutti sbraitano, ma nessuno ha il coraggio di ribellarsi*.

Comunque, non mi sembra il caso di mettersi a gridare durante la notte quando si ha l'insonnia. Per questa ragione vi chiedo: il verbo "sbraitare" può avere un uso figurato che non implichi parlare a voce alta o gridare? Si tratta di un uso letterario o è invece comune?

Answer (score 2):

> Comunque, non mi sembra il caso di mettersi a gridare durante la notte quando si ha l'insonnia.

Beh, sicuramente non è il caso, ma se lo vedi come un gesto di disappunto ha senso che capiti.

> il verbo "sbraitare" può avere un uso figurato che non implichi parlare a voce alta o gridare?

Non che io sappia (salvo il caso citato da Josh61), oltretutto appunto, come ho già detto implicitamente sopra ritengo che nel brano sia usato in modo letterale. Se ci fai caso nessuna delle altre azioni è usata in senso figurato (in particolare "sbuffa", "finge di dormire", e "strizza gli occhi" sembrano voler descrivere la situazione in senso letterale), il che suggerisce che anche lo sbraitare non lo sia.

> Si tratta di un uso letterario o è invece comune?

È molto comune, assolutamente non letterario.

Answer (score 1):

Il termine ***[sbraitare](http://dizionari.repubblica.it/Italiano/S/sbraitare.php)*** nel brano  viene probabilmente usato nel senso figurato di protestare, indignarsi:

> - Vociare concitatamente, scompostamente, quasi urlando: sbraitava come un ossesso di avere ragione
> - (per  estensione) Protestare, ribellarsi, mostrarsi indignato contro qualcuno o qualcosa: *sbraitare contro il governo*

(Hoepli)

Comment: E questo senso figurato non implica parlare a voce alta o gridare? Si tratta di un uso comune di "sbraitare"?

Comment: Non vedo perché uno che soffre di insonnia non possa sbraitare, parlare ad alta voce, per nervosismo od altri motivi. Può essere giusto un'esclamazione  che nel silenzio della notte risuona come uno sbraitare.

Comment: Dunque, se ho capito bene, "sbraitare" anche nel senso di mostrarsi indignato o ribellarsi implica parlare a voce alta o gridare. È così?

Comment: Sì, sbraitare  significa parlare ad alta voce in maniera scomposta e concitata.  Penso che l'uso fatto nel brano voglia sottolineare un disaggio, uno sfogo più che il gesto fisico dello sbraitare.

Comment: @charo, 'nel silenzio della notte' la voce, anche senza essere alta, risuona. Quantomeno nel contorno di dove viene prodotta.

Answer (score -3):

La definizione del Treccani è obsoleta, scorretta o, comunque, imprecisa, ciò perché 'sbraitare' non implica necessariamente una 'voce alta'. Infatti, essa -- la voce --, può anche essere normale, giusto quello che serve acché possa essere sentita.

Peraltro, a suffragio di quanto sopra, 'sbraitare silenziosamente' non è neanche riportato nell'elenco degli ossimori italiani, sebbene uno che sbraitasse silenziosamente dovrebbe essere portato subito al più vicino centro d'igiene mentale.

Comment: @Charo, ti piace la risposta?

Comment: Scusa per il -1, ma questa secondo me è proprio sbagliata. Non direi che sbraitare sia un sinonimo (per esempio) di gridare dato che non è proprio la stessa cosa, ma certamente direi che implica una voce alta. Treccani non è l'unico vocabolario a riportare la voce alta come parte dell'azione, basta una ricerca su Google per convincersene.

Comment: @kos, io non temo il Treccani perché, essendo un parlante e un ascoltante, sono più aggiornato.

Comment: Un parlante e un ascoltante ?